# Can't override background color

Tags: vim

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=234 guibg=#2c2d27
let &colorcolumn=join(range(81,999),",")
```

When I search for words that fall into this range, the background color for the word does not show up. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. The priorities of search highlighting and hlsearch are fixed, you can only specify the priority when using `matchadd()`, but even with a high number there, I wasn't able to override the `'colorcolumn'`. It appears that this is completely separate (like syntax highlighting), and cannot be overruled.

Anyway, the colorcolumn is meant to be a single (or multiple few) columns, not the broad area you've created with your `range()` trick. So in a way, you're suffering under your own cleverness: You've misused a built-in feature, and now complain about the side effects.

So, move back to a single colorcolumn, or use the emulation used in older Vim versions, `matchadd()` with a low priority:

```
:call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%>80v', -10)
```